# How to mock method which uses Reactor core Mono function

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following class which contains two methods one to get a total no of messages from the queue and the second to process the messages.

```
@RestController
public class  JMSController {

    public String process(){

        int totalMessage= getNumberOfMessageInQueue() ;
        // rest of the code

   }


    public int getNumberOfMessageInQueue(String queueName) {

        Mono<Integer> messageCount= Mono.fromCallable( () -> {
             return jmsTemplate.browse(queueName, (session, queueBrowser) ->
                    Collections.list(queueBrowser.getEnumeration()).size()
            );
        }).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5L)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());

        return  messageCount.block();
    }

}
```

I am writing junit test case for method `process()`.

My question is : How to mock `getNumberOfMessageInQueue` method ?

Comment: Can you define 'mock' for this context.  Do you want to have this method just return some constant `int`?  Do you want to 'mock' the result of `jmsTemplate.browse`?

Comment: Why do you want to mock `getNumberOfMessageInQueue` ? You should be mocking `jmsTemplate.browse`.